# I want to redirect link using header location

Tags: php

I want to redirect that link `www.name.com/movie/movie.php?mode=list` when I access link `www.domain.com/movie/` without `www.name.com/movie/movie.php?mode=list` using `$_GET['mode']` function. But, I can't redirect it. when I access `www.name.com/movie/` link, happening access denied.So, I want to redirect it.
**Here is my code**

```
if(!isset($_GET['mode'])) || (!isset($_POST['mode'])){

    $loc = "Location: www.name.com/movie/movie.php?mode=list";
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header($loc);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to link on the same website
just do this

```
header("Location: /movie/movie.php?mode=list");
```

If you want to write full url or link to other domain
Link should be start with `http://` or `https://`

```
header("Location: http://www.name.com/movie/movie.php?mode=list");
```